# Curl request for implicit grant type on fiware keyrock?

Tags: node.js, fiware, identity-management, identitymanager, fiware-keyrock

I wanted to fire a curl request for implicit grant type on fiware idm. I have gone through the official docs of fiware idm-

https://fiware-idm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/oauth/oauth_documentation/index.html

Implicit grant type exists in fiware idm, but while making a curl request it throws the following error:

```
{"error":"unsupported_grant_type"}
```

My curl request is as follows:

```
curl -X POST -H 
"Authorization: Basic $(echo -n 56c32d7-c991-4da0-8b0a-018461ac583e6:0ec8898c-3bc7-12cd-8abd-0d6abgh01c56 | base64 -w 0)" --header "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d "grant_type=implicit&username=admin@test.com&password=1234" https://Keyrock_Host:Keyrock_Port/oauth2/token --insecure
```

Does anyone know about it ?

Answer (score 0):

The body of your request is incorrect, it appears you are passing in the required data for the **Password Grant** not the **Implicit Grant**.

For an **Implicit Grant** in OAuth2 you need a `token` or `code` request passing the `client-id`:

```
GET /oauth/authorize?
response_type=token&
client_id={{client-id}}&
state=xyz&
redirect_uri={{callback_url}}
```

This is the case where an application itself is requesting access to resources, and the `client-id` and `callback-url` ar already registered within the IDM

see:

- https://fiware-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/securing-access/index.html#implicit-grant
- https://auth0.com/blog/oauth2-implicit-grant-and-spa/